# How can I pass dynamic value to pipe in Angular 8

Tags: angular

How can i pass dynamic value to pipe in Angular.

```
<tr *ngFor="let users of Users | sortpipe: 'name'">
        <td>{{ users.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ users.email }}</td>
        <td>{{ users.mobile }}</td>
        <td><input type="button" (click)="getUser(users._id)" class="btn btn-info" value="Edit"></td>
        <td><input type="button" (click)="deleteUser(users._id)" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete"></td>
</tr>
```

I would like to pass dynamic value at `sortpipe: 'name'` instead of name on click event.

Comment: No i don't want to pass users object

Comment: Please also add your implementation of the `sortpipe`

Comment: can you explain your use case?

Comment: I want use it for sorting

Comment: it's just add a optional parameter in the function "transform", e.g. `transform(data:any[],field?:string){}`, see the docs; https://angular.io/guide/pipes#custom-pipes

Comment: i have that on, my question is how can i place dynamic value to pipe parameter in `.html` file

Comment: please make sure you read the Angular team appendix on the reason [why orderBy pipe was removed in Angular 2+.](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe) TLDR: Performance. sorting in a pipe, will probably require the pipe to be declared as `impure` which will heavily affect performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you just create a property and pass that property as pipe parameter when the proprty change this will update the pipe parameter value

```html
<div>
  set sort key
    <input type="button" name="key" (click)="name ='name'" value="name">
    <input type="button" name="key" (click)="name ='mobile'" value="mobile">
</div>

<div>
  method 
  <label >
    <input type="radio" name="method" [(ngModel)]="method" value="asc"> ASC
    </label>

  <label >
    <input type="radio" name="method" [(ngModel)]="method" value="desc"> DESC
    </label>
</div>

<tr *ngFor="let users of Users | sort: name : method ">
  ....
</tr>
```

*component*

```
export class AppComponent  {
 name = "name"; // 
 method="asc"  //  

  Users = [...]
}
```

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-govmhq)

Comment: i want to pass value on click.

Comment: yes you can like this `<button (click) ="name ='firstName'">first name</button>` or you can use radio button just update the name property and the pipe will be updated

Comment: @SavanPadaliya hppy to help check this demo   https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-govmhq

Answer (score 1):

Your template.html... change `'name'` to class object reference `name`, and then in your component you have to define this class member variable, and assign value to it...

```
<tr *ngFor="let users of Users | sortpipe: name " >
    <td>{{ users.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ users.email }}</td>
    <td>{{ users.mobile }}</td>
    <td><input type="button" (click)="getUser(users._id)" 
                 class="btn btn-info" value="Edit">
    </td>
    <td><input type="button" (click)="deleteUser(users._id)" 
                 class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete">
    </td>
</tr>
```

and in your component.ts file...

```
export class AppComponent {
     name = 'name'
}
```